# Datagrid error when casting to model only when isReadOnly is false?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have Datagrid  and I want to cast the data from each row to a specific model.
the casting code is

```
        private List<SearchAndReplaceModel> getSelectedWordes()
        {
           DGKeywords.UnselectAllCells();
           var repo = new SearchAndReplaceRepository();
          List<SearchAndReplaceModel> selectedWordes = new List<SearchAndReplaceModel>();
           List<SearchAndReplaceModel> dataFromGrid=DGKeywords.Items.Cast<SearchAndReplaceModel>().ToList();
           if (dataFromGrid != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < dataFromGrid.Count; i++)
            {
                selectedWordes.Add ( dataFromGrid[i]);
            }
           return selectedWordes;
        }
```

the stranger thing is that the code is working perfectly when the property of  Datagrid `isReadOnly=true` but there is exception when I change it to `isReadOnly=false`

the exception :

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in System.Core.dll An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.OfType()` extension method instead of `.Cast()`:

```
private List<SearchAndReplaceModel> getSelectedWordes()
{
   DGKeywords.UnselectAllCells();
   return DGKeywords.Items.OfType<SearchAndReplaceModel>().ToList();
}
```

or it maybe simpler to iterate `DGKeywords.ItemsSource` (depending on how DataGrid is filled with data)